# Lacking motivation in undergraduate studying

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm an undergraduate student in mathematics based in Pisa, Italy. My university has always had kind of a reputation for being hard, although I can't compare it to others since it's the only one I've ever attended. I'm doing okay, I'm currently in my third year and I'm almost done with the bigger exams (real analysis I and II, introduction to general and algebraic topology, abstract algebra...). I'm also doing much better (not trying to sound pretentious) than many of my year's students, in fact the vast majority of them quit before the end of the first year and many of the remaining ones just re-attended the first year. The point is, I'm starting to lose a bit of motivation. I like what I'm studying, but I'm certainly not great at it, and I really have no idea what I'm going to do afterwards. I could like becoming an actual mathematician maybe, but I don't think I'd go really far with it since here are a lot of really brilliant students that would outsmart most of the teachers (I'm not kidding, the Scuola Normale Superiore really makes the competition kick in). So the question, briefly, is the following: you average mathematicians, you normal people like me who knew from the start you wouldn't prove the Riemann hypothesis, how did you cope with that feeling? Have you ever felt some kind of inferiority complex? What have you become after graduation? Why? How is the world out there? Does it really need another meh mathematician, or would it benefit more from me just becoming a trashman? Feels a little weird to ask something like this, but this feeling is spread out across most of the students in my mathematics department. A girl I know has just two weeks ago passed the real analysis II and algebra exams (she PASSED THEM!), and is now wondering about whether she should change course and study medicine; that's a bit drastic, me and all of her friends have told her such, but her answer has been "my will to do maths is vastly inferior to the amount of work required in order to keep up with uni". And we're all kinda in that situation, no one excluded. So, the only reply has been "well, you've made it this far. Now it's a bit late." but that's not true. That can't be a motivation for keeping on with maths. I didn't think this would bother me as much as it did, but the fact that everyone has the same feelings as me towards uni has multiplied my anxiety, I don't know why. I also started thinking about my girlfriend's brother: he hasn't even completed high school (he's one year older than me), but he loves programming and has found a secure job with a more than adequate wage in that field. I don't have the same passion towards maths as he has towards IT, as doesn't anyone of my friends at uni. Isn't that weird? The more I study maths, the more I love it and the more I hate studying it. Sorry for the ramble, but being the rational cynic piece of crap that I am it's difficult to put into words my feelings. I know that maths is difficult on its own, I also don't really know what kind of answer I want, I'm just sharing thoughts. I have a lot of friends who are trying the algebra exam for the sixth time, and they're getting very demotivated and kinda make me feel bad that I'm even asking this since I have managed to pass most of the more difficult exams. I don't really know how to express what i'm thinking, so let's just make an example: I had my general and algebraic topology oral exam the other day, and I had to find the fundamental group of the real projective plane. Here's the answer i gave:

> If $G$ and $H$ are a right and a left action on a set $X$ such that $(gx)h = g(xh) \ \forall g \in G, h \in H, x \in X$ then $\forall x \in X, \theta_x:G \mapsto H$ which maps $g$ to the only $h: gx=xh$ is a group homomorphism, in particular $H \simeq G/$Ker$(\theta_x) = G/$Stab$_H(x)$. If we consider a topological space $E$ and a group $G$ acting on it, then if such action is compatible with the monodromy of $E/G$, as a corollary $\pi_1(E/G) \simeq G/p_*\pi_1(E)$ where $p_*$ is the induced homomorphism of the covering map $E \mapsto E/G$. As a special case, the fundamental group of the real $n$-dimensional projective space is $\pi_1(S^n/\mathbb{Z}_2)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2/p_*\pi_1(S^n)$ and since $S^n$ is simply connected $\forall n>1$ the induced subgroup is trivial and therefore the fundamental group of the projective space is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Ok, let's recap. I knew what I was talking about, I had studied that, and my professor noticed it (got full marks on the exam btw), but after saying that I just paused for five seconds and realized how MOTHERF***ING COMPLICATED this is. And this is a very basic theorem, not even the proof of SVK (which I fortunately wasn't asked)! Like, explaining this thing to someone not into maths would be quite a long adventure, but it's treated as trivial in this course (as it was by me too, until I had to say it out loud during the exam)! I would never, EVER come up with anything similar, so what hope do I have to become at least a decent mathematician if even such a ""trivial"" theorem is beyond me? Are most mathematicians like me? If so, how do they live with it?

*(Sorry for bad grammar)*

Comment: This is probably not the right site for these kinds of questions, although I empathise with your situation.

Comment: It's totally ok to do other things. Applied math / Data science / programming / biotech (for example) have a lot of really exciting stuff going on.

Comment: @YiFan Oh I'm sorry, I posted here because it's the place where I'm most likely to get answers from people with actual experience in the field of research and/or other students feeling like me

Comment: @OP- You seem to compare yourself to others close around you. My advice: stop doing this. Do what you want to do. Also, stop caring so much about how others are judging you: people will always judge you, so you may as well do something you enjoy whilst they’re doing so. The main reason I studied maths at uni was because I loved maths (I still do). I just find some topics fascinating and will spend my time learning more about it. I don’t give a rats ass what anyone thinks about that

Comment: @AdamRubinson that's what most people tell me, but my gut tells me that since I have to live in the mathematical community I feel like I should actually contribute to it in some way

Comment: So you’re in 3rd year. I’m guessing that’s the final year of your course? So what is the actual main problem in your life? You’re thinking of doing a Master’s? You can’t seriously be thinking of dropping out in 3rd year if it’s your last year and you’re already half way through it, and you’re doing fine in exams. If you don’t complete your degree, you’ll have nothing to show for it. Your CV will be blank and you’ll be fucked. Finish your degree and re-evaluate your life after your degree is finished...

Comment: Also I must add I find it disturbing when you say, “I knew from the start I wasn’t going to solve the Riemann Hypothesis”. You can’t have possibly known that. I pity  people who have a “can’t-do” attitude when it isn’t called for. It’s all too common for people to have this attitude nowadays

Comment: I never mentioned dropping out, I like this subject (and I want at least something for all this goddamn effort I put in it), and I'll definitely graduate this year/next year. The thing is, I feel a little discouraged being side by side with many people who could actually do proper maths after their degree. Also, yes, while unlikely, it's possible that an average mathematician will solve the Riemann Hypothesis, but seeing students graduate in just one year and a half when I struggle for doing that in literally double that time leaves me kinda perplexed at the idea

Comment: You have imposter syndrome. Get rid of it.

Comment: @Shalop I don't really think that's what's what's going on, but besides that, the question is more about other mathematician's experiences as to how that career is for people with a very average intelligence. It's not a very precise question but that's intentional

Answer (score 6):

Might be a bit much to answer the whole question, so I'm going to concentrate on

> *you normal people like me who knew from the start you wouldn't prove the Riemann hypothesis, how did you cope with that feeling?*

I enrolled for a Ph.D. in number theory, struggled but did manage to complete it.  One examiner's comment was that there was not much in my thesis but it was well written so I deserved to pass.  I thought this was absolutely accurate, and it confirmed for me three things which I already knew.  (1) By "community" standards I'm a good mathematician.  (2) By professional standards I'm not a good mathematician - in fact scarcely a mathematician at all, really.  (3) I'm a good writer.

So what did I do?  Got an academic position (which I still have 30 years later) and concentrated on teaching, which I love.  Not sure I could cope with school teaching, but at the (slightly) higher level of undergraduate teaching, I enjoy having a good understanding of basic post-secondary mathematics, helping students to understand it and trying to help them see how beautiful it is.  And writing it elegantly for them.  I do occasional very low-level research, not directed, just if I notice something interesting I try to understand the whole problem, write it up carefully, and now and then (very rarely) this turns into a publishable paper.

Also very important is that I'm closely involved with other activities like music and wilderness sports, so that my career (which from many people's point of view would have to be considered spectacularly unsuccessful) is not the only thing in my life.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, I really appreciate that, I'm happy to hear of some concrete experience. You really didn't answer though: how did you cope with the fact that as a professional mathematician you weren't able to shine? Did you just come to terms with the fact that you weren't able to (I don't want to sound offensive, I'm just taking this from your answer), or did you decide that it wasn't how you wanted to continue your career and moved on, or you focused on your other hobbies, or what?

Comment: It wasn't really a problem for me.  Just accept reality, work out what I am good at and follow that.

Comment: @DottorMaelstrom: I second this answer. To me the most important is that you do your best at what you can do, and accept what you cannot, and recognize that it is not so important what you end up doing as long as you don't waste what you have. =)

Answer (score 4):

As David said, it is complicated answering all. However I have to tell you a couple of things.

First one, I am also at college (electrical engineering), where I deal with a lot of math (of course, not as much as you). And it happens the same: lot's of people give up, there are some "brilliant" students and so on. What I have to tell you is:

> If you love studying math or anything, keep doing it. Do not care about the others' grades or achievements, such as being able to prove Riemann Hypothesis.

I had been thinking about it for a while and realized that it is kind of impossible measuring if someone is "better" than you. Honestly, it is even hard for you measure yourself, sometimes. Let's take me as example: When I was a teenager, I had trouble with Linear and Quadratics Equations; I didn't passed to college at the first time, since my math grade wasn't as good as it should have been (it was good, but not as good for engineering) and sometimes I get really bad grades at college. On the other hand, I usually get very good grades, my grades usually are on top 10 (because I go crazy when get a bad one, then I study 24/7 so as to overcome it), and mostly important, I love studying math and physics. Since I love this, I think "anything" is possible, therefore I do not give up.

Additionally:

1) Once, my Vectorial Calculus professor asked for us solving some exercises, then the smartest in class finished it first and incredibly quickly. Right after when he got out of class, one of my colleagues asked the professor: "How come? He must be super inteligent!!". Then, surprisingly, my professor replied: "No, he just know something you do not yet.".

2) About those who achieve "greatness", I believe that most of these would agree that hard work is greater than anything. Their careers were built block by block. Also, if they did not knew something (which they didn't), they would just study it until they understand it.

You do not need to worry at all, I should knew some stuff, you should knew some stuff and most people should knew some stuff. The thing is: what are you going to do having this information? Get to understand or give up?

Wish you luck and the best!